# how to upgrade eclipse codename one version from 6.0 to 6.5 (then to 6.5.1)?

Tags: codenameone

TWO very related questions in this post.

- How to install 6.5 & 6.5.1 in eclipse(more detail below)
- Intellij Toolbox last version supported is 2019.2.4 but looks like codeone plugin doesn't support it?

In intellij, codenameone 6.5.1 simulator is not working(font is way too small) but it's working in 6.0.0 with my eclipse(from when I played with it 6 months ago).  I am trying to test out each version to see what the latest version is that is not broken for me(hopefully at least 6.5).  When I go to eclipse marketplace, there is no upgrade and it just shows this for codename one (eclipse verison 2020-06 as I clicked update all)

[image]

I don't see a way to download a zip file and install it in eclipse and only see the install from marketplace method here

https://www.codenameone.com/download.html#step2

Is there a zip download for eclipse somewhere I can try of 6.5, then 6.5.1?

I also want to try to downgrade my intellij version but we also need the latest so I grabbed the new intellij toolbox but this only goes back to version 2019.2.4.  The compatibility list on codenameone plugin is such

[image]

I wonder about that first line for 6.5.1.  A dot release and they added support all the way back to 2016 version which 6.5 didn't have?  Seems like a type.  Also, 6.5.1 did not work with latest intellij and honestly getting worn down in playing the version mismatch game of uninstall/install to see what works and doesn't work (it's just takes quite a bit of time).

**If anyone can post a STABLE list of IDE version / plugin version they are using, I would LOVE to know that** <- If I know that, I will just jump to that.  I can cope with eclipse or intellij.  In fact, eclipse debugging is way better and intellij refactoring is way better so I am always torn between each.

Trying 2019.1.4 with many versions next.

Comment: About the font size, you can increase it. See https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2537#issuecomment-459377903 and https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2537#issuecomment-460374197

Answer (score 0):

Figure this out finally.  Not sure exactly but this repo https://github.com/deanhiller/codenameOneExamples

now works with latest intelij 2020.1.3 !!